# wordpress loop multiple category

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

What I am trying to achieve

```
<div>
posts from category "vitejte"
</div>
<div>
posts from category "novinky"
</div>
```

This is my index.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="body_resize">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="body_small2">
            <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php if ( in_category('vitejte') ) { ?>

                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <img src="wp-content/themes/trywp/images/img_1.jpg" alt="picture" width="353" height="102" />
                    <?php the_content('Read More...'); ?>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php _e('Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "vitejte"'); ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <?php _e('Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "vitejte2"'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="body_small">
                <h2>Novinky</h2>
                <?php if ( in_category('novinky') ) { ?>
                    <p class="data"> 20 / May / 09</p>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <p><?php the_content('Read More...'); ?> <a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a></p>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php _e('Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "novinky"'); ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <?php _e('Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "vitejte2"'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that it returns the posts as requested but it returns also

> Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "vitejte"

and

> Prosím vytvořte článek v kategorii "novinky"

which are in the else statement and should not be returned
BTW: the text means smt like "please create a post in "vitejte" category

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Once you've been though the loop once, `have_posts()` will be false - you're seeing the content of the `else` after the `endwhile`.  Try calling `rewind_posts()` before the second loop (ie before the second `<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`).  That should allow you to loop through the posts again.